# Exporting MSSQL table info to a csv file?

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a MSSQL database table I'm accessing on a PHP page.  I'm displaying certain rows on the  page using a SELECT ALL WHERE query.  Now I need a button to export the SELECT ALL WHERE query to a .csv file.  I need a little help getting started with this.

I have a function to create the page that could create the page to export:

```
public function SelectAllWhereFetch( $table, $where, $extra = "", $columns = "*" ) {
$tsql = "SELECT $columns FROM " . $table . " WHERE " . $where . $extra;
        $stmt = $this->ExecuteDontFreeQuery( $tsql );

        $result = mssql_query($query);

        // Checking for and creating table names
            $i = 0;
            echo '<html><body><table><tr>';
            while ($i < mssql_num_fields($result))
                {
            $meta = mssql_fetch_field($result, $i);
            echo '<td>' . $meta->name . '</td>';
            $i = $i + 1;
                }
        echo '</tr>';

        // Returning all rows in table
        while ( ($row = mssql_fetch_row($result))) 
            {
            $count = count($row);
            $y = 0;
            echo '<tr>';
            while ($y < $count)
                    {
                $c_row = current($row);
                echo '<td>' . $c_row . '</td>';
                next($row);
                $y = $y + 1;
                    }
            echo '</tr>';
                }
            mssql_free_result($result);

            echo '</table></body></html>';

    }
```

Here's the "if" statement for the button action:

```
if( $_REQUEST['exporting']) {

$vastreamline = $dataConnection->SelectAllWhereFetch("applicants",  
"loan_purpose='VA Streamline' AND statusdate >= '1/1/2011'", 
"ORDER BY statusdate DESC" );

        header("Content-type: text/x-csv");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=streamline.csv");
        echo $vastreamline;
}
```

Here's the button action:

```
 <div class="span3">
      <input type="hidden" name="exporting" value="true">
      <input type="submit" class="btn primary" value="Export CSV">
 </div>
```

I seem to be making a connection to the MSSQL database because I can display information.  I just can't figure out the syntax to get the button to export a csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your button is not inside of a form, try:

```
<form action="yourexportpage.php" method="POST">
    <div class="span3">
        <input type="hidden" name="exporting" value="true">
        <input type="submit" class="btn primary" value="Export CSV">
    </div>
</form>
```

Also change your PHP export page to:

```
if( $_REQUEST['exporting']) {

    header("Content-type: text/x-csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=streamline.csv");

    $dataConnection->SelectAllWhereFetch("applicants",  
    "loan_purpose='VA Streamline' AND statusdate >= '1/1/2011'", 
    "ORDER BY statusdate DESC" );
}
```

Comment: Adding the from tag does give my button functionality.  It exports the current HTML page I'm posting to as a .csv file.  However, I just want the table information from my query.

Comment: @post.72 Try modifying your PHP export page to the revised code.